# How to enter Advanced options for Ubuntu in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: 23.10, tpm, rescue-mode

I tried to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting the machine, but neither of them are working. I need to rescue my soduers file in *Advanced options for Ubuntu*. Attaching the disk to another machine is not working as well, since disk was encrypted by TPM full disk encryption feature of Ubuntu 23.10, during installation there is no asking for input passphrase for encryption. I cannot unlock this encryption disk on another machine, but I have the recovery key output from the `snap recovery --show-keys` command.